# Why Object.Selectnodes(XPath) gets 1st node value if former node is empty

Tags: excel, xml, vba, xmldom

Why `Object.SelectNodes(XPath)` gets as 1st node value second node value if former node (real 1st node value) is empty.
Example below:

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
    <person>
    </person>
    <person>
           <name>Peter</name>
    </person>
</Document>
```

**VBA code:**

```vb
Dim j as Integer
Dim FileToOpen as Variant
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="XML Files (*.xml), *.xml", _
Title:="Choose XML document ", MultiSelect:=False)
Set XDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    XDoc.async = False: XDoc.validateOnParse = False
    XDoc.Load FileToOpen

    For j = 1 To 2
        Set tofields = XDoc.SelectNodes("//Document/person/name")
        If Not (tofields.Item(j)) Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print tofields.Item(j).Text
        Else
            Debug.Print "Nothing"
        End If
    Next j
```

**Result:**

```
Peter
Nothing
```

Why is not "Nothing" on the first place in the result ? How to reach that ? If parent node does not include 1st child node, 1st iteration is omitted.
Thank you.

Comment: Posted an answer and a working example to your code (late binding MSXML2 in its latest version 6.0); don't forget to enforce variable declaration by using `Option Explicit` in your module's declaration head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Enumeration in XMLDOM differs from XPath**

**XMLDOM** syntax enumerates `nodes` as **zero based** items in a `NodeList`, i.e. starting from `0`, whereas *XPath expressions* identifying subnodes start from `1` (e.g. calling a first name item `"//name[1]"`). This mistakes in considering `2` as the last item index instead of looping from `.Item(0)` to `.Item(1)` in your example code. You get the number of found items results via the node list's `.Length` method (2 minus 1 results in 1 as the last index number, thus giving a name node series of 0 to 1).

Furthermore it's recommended to reference **MSXML2 version 6.0** *(`MSXML2.DOMDocument` refers to the last stable version 3.0 used only for compatibility reasons)*.

Further hints assuming that you want loop through all **persons** in your XML document (the nodelist in the OP delivers one item only, as the `name` node exists only once):

- The expressions `xDoc.SelectNodes("//Document/person")` or `//person` would search the defined node set at any hierarchy Level within a given node structure. So it's less time consuming to use unambigously `Set toFields = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("person")` in your case.
- The following code example wouldn't show the `Nothing` case, as the node list displays two `name` nodes only (`For i = 0 To toFields.Length - 1`). *Just in order to check your original attempt you could enumerate up to three items by changing intently to `For i = 0 To toFields.Length` (i.e. `0 to 2`).*

**Additional link**

Analyze your XML structure via recursive calls; a working function can be found at [Parse XML using XMLDOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54157472/vba-parse-xml-using-xmldocument/54158413#54158413).

**Code example**

```
    Dim xDoc As Object, toFields As Object
    Dim myName As String, i As Long
    Set xDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")   ' recommended version 6.0 (if late bound MSXML2)
    xDoc.async = False: xDoc.validateOnParse = False
    ' ...

    Set toFields = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("person")
    For i = 0 To toFields.Length - 1
        If Not toFields.Item(i) Is Nothing Then
            If toFields.Item(i).HasChildNodes Then
               myName = toFields.Item(i).SelectSingleNode("name").Text
               Debug.Print i, IIf(Len(Trim(myName)) = 0, "**Empty name", myName)

            Else
               Debug.Print i, "**No name node**"
            End If
        Else
            Debug.Print i, "**Nothing**"            ' shouldn't be needed from 0 to .Length-1 items :-)
        End If
    Next i
```